# Twilio Voice - Where can I find Mic Stream that is used on call

Tags: android, twilio, microphone, mediarecorder

When talking on a call from a Twilio number to a regular number, I want to integrate background music during call. I want to entertain my users with selecting funny audios syncing with voice.

I have searched Open-Source Twilio library for mic stream but I am unable to find on the below link.
https://github.com/twilio/twilio-java